# ViewCell height doesnt work Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, tableview

I'm beginner at Xcode and I need some help with viewcell in table view.

This is the properties for my viewcell:

[image]

When i tried to run the simulator it become something like this:

[image]

my viewcontroller

```
import UIKit
import SwiftyJSON
import Kingfisher

class CakeViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource {

    //MARK : Properties


    var cakeArray = [Cake]()

    @IBOutlet weak var testImage: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return cakeArray.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cellIdentifier = "CakeTableViewCell"
        //        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CakeCategoryTableViewCell"/*Identifier*/, for: indexPath)
        guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as? CakeTableViewCell  else {
            fatalError("The dequeued cell is not an instance of cakeViewCell.")
        }
        //cell.textLabel?.text = cake_category[indexPath.row]
        let cakeObj = cakeArray[indexPath.row]
        cell.cakeLabel.text = cakeObj.product
        return cell
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        print("Load Initial Data")

        loadInitialDataFromJson(category : "Reguler Cake")


        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func loadInitialDataFromJson(category:String)
    {
        APIManager.sharedInstance.getCakeByCategory(category: category, onSuccess: {json in DispatchQueue.main.async {
            let status = json["status"].stringValue
            //let message = json["message"].stringValue


            if status == "OK"
            {

                for (key, subJson) in json["list_produk"] {
                    //print(subJson["id_product"])
                    var arrayVariant = [Variant]()
                    for(key,subsJson) in subJson{
                        arrayVariant.append(Variant(size:subsJson["size"].stringValue,price:subsJson["price"].intValue)!)
                    }
                    self.cakeArray.append(Cake(id_product:subJson["id_product"].stringValue,product:subJson["product"].stringValue,description:subJson["description"].stringValue,imageURL:subJson["images"].stringValue,variant:arrayVariant)!)
                }
                self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
                self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 150
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }else{
                print("Not Ok")
            }

            }}, onFailure: {error in let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: error.localizedDescription, preferredStyle: .alert)
                alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Dismiss", style: .default, handler: nil))
                self.show(alert, sender: nil)
        })

    }


    /*
    // MARK: - Navigation

    // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
        // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    }
    */

}
```

and my tableviewcell

```
import UIKit


class CakeTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    // MARK : Properties
    @IBOutlet weak var cakeImage: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var cakeLabel: UILabel!


    @IBAction func addToCart(_ sender: UIButton) {

    }

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

}
```

Any idea why this happening??

I've created some views with tableview and it has worked normally.

Comment: `self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 150` and `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` may rely on auto layout calculations to determine the actual cell height - how is your cell laid out? Do you constraints which link to the top and bottom constraints of the cells view (directly or indirectly)?

Comment: at first i tried without
self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 150 and UITableViewAutomaticDimension and its doest work ,thats why i tried to use it, didnt use any contraint, just default setup

Comment: ah i see thats why its doesnt work, ok the answer from @tarek hemdan work . thank's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to adjust your cell hight call in your cakeViewController

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat
    {
        return 100.0;//Choose your custom row height
    }
```

Comment: its work, can u explain it ? why i must override the function heightForRowAt? can we just adjust it directly from the storyboard properties?

Comment: @dmh : If you not set height, it will using the default value (44px). But in your case, if you want the cell height is automatic scale base on your text, you should read the tutorial of the auto-resizing cell

Comment: ah i see, Ok, Thank you so much